# How do I find my SSID for LAN on my raspberry pi 2?

Tags: wifi, pi-2

-Raspberry pi 2
-Trying to install a 3dprinting OS
-needs SSID for LAN

How should I find this?

Comment: google `linux SSID for LAN`

Comment: Try `iwlist wlan0 scan`